# How does it arise that there are two Colorado rivers, and how does one distinguish between them?

Tags: united-states

The storm in Houston has drawn to my attention, a fact of which I was previously unaware, that there are two quite separate Colorado rivers.

In Britain we have various instances of rivers with the same name e.g. Avon, Ouse etc. But we usually distinguish them by talking about "The Great Ouse" and the "Yorkshire Ouse" etc.

Please could someone explain to me how it arose that there were two Colorado Rivers, And if I describe one as "the Texas Colorado", what do I call the other?

Comment: I think Wikipedia covers the history of the naming, while it disambiguates with [Colorado River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_River) and [Colorado River(Texas)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_River_(Texas)).

Comment: Not sure this is a history question;  based on @SteveBird's comment, I'm not sure this is a non-trivial question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: I would describe this question as barely history, and barely non-trivial.

Comment: @Mark C.Wallace The only "geography site" I could find seemed far too technical. I apologise if I have pushed the boundaries of "history", but I did find Tom Au's answer interesting.

Comment: Agree that @TomAu 's analysis is the perfect summary.  The absence of a SE is not a justification to shoehorn a question into the least wrong SE. Historical sources and methods will be only peripherally useful in resolving this question.  More serious though is that the question appears to be answered by Wikipedia and the question does not address the shortcomings of the Wikipedia answer. Between Mr. Au's summary and the existing answer, I won't vote to close, but if I did, it would be on the basis that the question is trivial unless it addresses Wikipedia's answer.

Comment: As a resident of neighboring Oklahoma...as a general rule-of-thumb, Texas has themselves one of everything. For example, I saw a video this morning of [horses being led out of a flooded corral](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZC8A_38J-E) that identified it on social media as being from "Cleveland" (no disambiguation). You kind of just have to know that **if a Texan is talking**, disambiguation is more likely to be used for Paris France than Paris Texas.

Comment: Interesting how you mention the [Avon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Avon) - I was always confused about the geography of that river (having family in Salisbury, and Stratford-upon-Avon and Avonmouth being quite well known to me as I was growing up). Not once had I ever heard any of the rivers being qualified as the Salisbury Avon or Shakespeare's Avon as the wiki page suggests.

Comment: @HorusKol I believe there are eight Avons in all, in the UK - four of which are in England (Avon having been a Celtic word for river.) The three most frequently confused are the Warwickshire Avon (sometimes called "Shakespeare's Avon") which joins the Severn at Tewkesbury, the Somerset Avon which empties into the Severn Estuary at Avonmouth, and the Salisbury Avon which joins the English Channel through Christchurch harbour. The fourth English Avon, I believe is entirely contained within the county of Devon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ["main" Colorado River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_River) starts in Colorado, goes southwest in that state and Utah, and heads west then south through Arizona before forming the California-Arizona border, and empties in the Gulf of California. I would just call it the Colorado River.

The [river you are talking about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_River_(Texas)) was named "Colorado" because it is "colored," but starts and ends in Texas, and I would call it the Texas Colorado River.

"Colored" in this context means the color of the soil, typically red or brown, and not non-soil colors such blue, purple, or green.

Comment: How do we know about the order in which these two rivers were named? Presumably they were named by Spanish explorers (maybe in the 17th or 18th century), rather than by early settlers?

Comment: nguffa: Fair point. I removed that reference.

Comment: @njuffa - That'd be a good question. Might even be a good question for here, if voters don't consider it trivial.

Comment: @TomAu: Clarification: The translation of *Colorado* from Spanish to English is actually *coloured red* rather than merely *coloured*. In both cases the rivers run through long stretches of red-tinted sandstone.

Comment: There's also the "Red River" (of the South) which forms the Texas-Oklahoma border... and the "Red River" (of the North) which forms the Minnesota-North Dakota border.

Comment: @"Colored" in this context would refer to the color of soils, such as red or brown. It would not refer to "non-soil" colors such as blue, green or purple.

Comment: @TomAu I have just read that in the 19th century the Colorado River which starts in Colorado was known as the Grand River - hence presumably why the Grand Canyon came to be so named.